# Paypal Integration Using NVP API

Tags: php, html, api, curl, paypal

I'm making ecommerce website for my client and i'm not familiar with payments gateways and API's so i'm facing problem to integrate paypal using Paypal NVP API . I found code snippets on stackoverflow that how to use api but i don't understand what is the html code i mean what is the code for paypal button (How paypal button will appear in webpage).

```
    $data = array(
    "METHOD" => "BMCreateButton",
    "VERSION" => "65.2",
    "USER" => "myname_api1.yahoo.com",
    "PWD" => "abcdefg",
    "SIGNATURE" => "adhiahduiahduohuaohdohaodhahoadhadhoa",
    "BUTTONCODE" => "ENCRYPTED",
    "BUTTONTYPE" => "BUYNOW",
    "BUTTONSUBTYPE" => "SERVICES",
    "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "US",
    "BUTTONIMAGE" => "reg",
    "BUYNOWTEXT" => "BUYNOW",
    "L_BUTTONVAR0" => "bussiness=myname@yahoo.com",
    "L_BUTTONVAR1" => "item_number=$product_id_array",
    "L_BUTTONVAR2" => "item_name=$product_name",
    "L_BUTTONVAR3" => "amount=$price",
    "L_BUTTONVAR4" => "currency_code=US",
    "L_BUTTONVAR5" => "no_shipping=1",
    "L_BUTTONVAR6" => "no_note=1",
    "L_BUTTONVAR7" => "notify_url=https://mysite.net/ecommerce/storescripts/my_ipn.php",
    "L_BUTTONVAR8" => "cancel_return=https://mysite.net/ecommerce/paypal_cancel.php",
    "L_BUTTONVAR9" => "return=https://mysite.net/ecommerce/checkout_complete.php"
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?'.http_build_query($data));
$nvpPayReturn = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

I add all my api credentials and other things but i dont undertsand what is the html code for the payment button to send data through api using form.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I need html code for button to run this api ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML Button Image:

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Here are the HTML Button Variables:

[PayPal Standard HTML Button Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/%20-%20HTML%20Variables)

Here's a basic Buy Now HTML Code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="testing">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: this method is useless totally unsecured.

Comment: I am only giving you the html variables for your code. You can secure this code, and just use the HTML Button Variables that were provided. Let me know if you need the instructions on securing the button code.

Comment: Is there any way to secure the html hidden variables ?

Comment: Here is the information from the developer site that details how to secure your buttons: [Securing Payment Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments)